# Prevent breaking at commas followed by tildes with `gq`

Tags: formatting

When I add `m` to `formatoptions` and have nonzero `textwidth`, Vim will insert line breaks after commas followed by tildes when I do `gq` in Normal mode.  In my case, Vim sometimes inserts a line break at the comma in lines like

```
... \dots,~$A$
```

converting it to

```
... \dots,
~$A$
```

when I would prefer to keep it whole, that is,

```
...
\dots,~$A$
```

instead.  According to `:help fo-table`

```
letter   meaning when present in 'formatoptions'
...
m   Also break at a multibyte character above 255.  This is useful for
    Asian text where every character is a word on its own.
```

So this seems strange to me, since I thought both `,` and `~` are part of ASCII.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior other than removing `m`?

Comment: Apparently, it is the comma that is causing the line break with `formatoptions=m`. Maybe you should file a bug report.